# Bash script doesn't expand *

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, expand

In bash script file I would like to check exiting of files according to mask:

```
 ls -la /home/user1/*log*
```

But I receive

```
 No such file or directory
```

When I run:

```
 ls -la /home/user1/app.log
```

it works.
How it could be fixed?

Comment: do you use that command within single-quotes?

Comment: Works for me, is it in quotes ?

Comment: it doesn't work for botn - for single and for double quotes

Comment: Could you post the complete script and the complete error message please?

Comment: Jidder - it works from command line, but doesn't work from inside of check_logs.sh file.

Comment: Please update your question with correct code used. Its working without " or ' but wouldn't work with quotes, And Its wont work both from command or inside script

Comment: @user710818. Make a new script that only contains `ls -la /home/user1/*log*`. If that works its something else in your script that you havent told us about

Comment: works for me too, as script - provided I don't double quote "/path/*file*"

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work only for specific folder. Now I am guessing why it works for /tmp/testuser but doesn't work for other folders...

Comment: @user710818 It would be helpful, if you can post the source or solution for the problem.

Comment: I didn't found solution yet. May it is related to permission... But strange that running from script file and from command line without "*" works both. But with "*" - works only from command line. I think also need check symbolic links, mounted paths....

Comment: Your question needs to include enough details to let someone else produce the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

From man bash:

Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \

and single quotes will preserve everything.

We use it on daily basis, when some path contains space, or some special character. We enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but I had a similar issue when executing a shell script from the `www-data` user (Apache user) on Ubuntu 16.04.
This command, executed in my script, solved the issue:

```
set +o noglob
```